# how to call LoadLibrary for my .so shared library from C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared, loadlibrary

I don't want any java in my small NDK application. I want to load a shared .so library. I want to call LoadLibrary for it directly from C++ using jni. Did anyone try that?

BTW I already packaged the .so library into apk together with main .so file.
Please also note i use Visual Studio 2015 for android development so no .mk files

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call loadLibrary(...) from C++ to use a shared library. You just need to link to it when you build your C++ code.

Have a look at the [native-activity example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk/native-activity) in Google's [NDK examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/android-mk). If you want to use the new experimental NDK support, you should refer to [these examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) instead.

**Update:** For Visual Studio users, perhaps this [tutorial on creating a native-activity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/12/05/developing-native-activity-android-applications/) would be more helpful.

Comment: thank you, that would be a correct thing to do. Unfortunatly i don't have access to android.mk file so i cannot use that mechanism because i use Visual Studio 2015 to develop for android and it has just bunch of weird XMLs and no .mk files(so no LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES)...

Comment: that is just standard native activity that  i already have. my problem i am not able now use shared .so library from my native activity. That tutorial doesn't cover that.

Comment: You'll need to find out how Visual Studio resolves dependencies for NDK apps. Using loadLibrary(...) is just the step needed to use that code from Java, but in those weird XMLs or some other piece of configuration there should be some delineation of dependencies. I can't help you more than that, as I don't have VS, but perhaps this example will reveal some answers: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/TwoLibs-Android-Library-6396e5c4/view/SourceCode#content    Good luck.

Comment: thank you for trying to help, we probably think alike cause i downloaded exactly that sample earlier and that sample if you look inside of it has .java file with calls to LoadLibrary to load those two .so libraries. But because i have no java code in my project that raised my original question of how can i call LoadLibrary from c++ directly to avoid making my project mixed c++/java cause i really want my activity to stay in c++.

Comment: I did notice that the solution file in that sample, TwoLibs.sln, mentions the C++ dependencies, but there might be more plumbing than that to consider. It only shows how to depend on other VS projects.

Comment: Think the question targets PlugIns